# Node.js - Clone .git repository using a personal access token and simple-git

Tags: node.js, git

I have a Node.js app. I want to clone a *private* repository from GitHub using this app. I have access to this repository. In an attempt to clone the repository from my Node.js app, I'm using [simple-git](https://github.com/steveukx/git-js#readme), with the following code:

```
const git = simpleGit();
git.clone('[repository-url]', './repository');
```

This code runs successfully. A directory named `repository` with the following structure is created:

```
/repository
  /.git
  .gitignore
```

However, this is *not* the contents of the repository. I successfully cloned a *public* repository using this code. This makes me believe that it's an authentication issue, even though no error is being shown. I [created a Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) and stored it in an environment variable. However, I can't figure out how to actually use that Personal Access Token when I clone my *private* repository.

How do I clone a *private* repository using a Personal Access Token using simple-git?

Answer (score 3):

```
const git = simpleGit({
   'some_url',
   {
     config: [
       `http.extraHeader=Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}`
     ]
   }
})
```

*- For ver 3.x.x*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [config plugin](https://github.com/steveukx/git-js#per-command-configuration) to add your access token as a custom header:

```
const git = simpleGit({
  config: [
   `Authorization: token ${TOKEN}`
  ]
});
```

You can also set up a `.netrc` file with your auth details which `simple-git` will pick up by default.